Terraform fail to retrieve app engine default service account
I need to create gcp app engine and give some permissions to default service account using terraform. The .tf file looks like this.
resource "google_app_engine_application" "app" {
  project     = "${var.project_id}"
  location_id = "${var.region}"
}
    
data "google_app_engine_default_service_account" "default" {
  project = "${var.project_id}"
}
    
resource "google_project_iam_member" "secretmanagerSecretAccessor" {
  project = "${var.project_id}"
  role    = "roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${data.google_app_engine_default_service_account.default.email}"
}

But terraform fails to run it on new project. I suppose because service account is not exist jet.
 Error: Invalid template interpolation value

   on main.tf line 35, in resource "google_project_iam_member" "secretmanagerSecretAccessor":
   35:   member  = "serviceAccount:${data.google_app_engine_default_service_account.default.email}"
     ├────────────────
     │ data.google_app_engine_default_service_account.default.email is null

 The expression result is null. Cannot include a null value in a string template.

Marko E, using project = var.project_id not helped. Same error message.

Can you try with project = var.project_id in the data source?

"I suppose because service account is not exist jet." Yes that would cause the error. What behavior do you want if the service account does not exist yet in the project? Are you managing the account with Terraform in any way?

@MatthewSchuchard I want to give permissions to default service account. I enable  app engine and then need to give permission to default service account.

Here's a list of things you could do to troubleshoot your issue:

check that the service account indeed exists in your project (and that the App Engine service is enabled)
check that Terraform executes with credentials providing enough privileges to actually read that information
are you on a recent enough version of both Terraform and the provider? There may be a bug there.

Also, the App Engine default GSA has a common name ("${var.project_id}@@appspot.gserviceaccount.com") that you can try to use without the need for the data block, and see if you can make it work that way.

On a side note, don't use interpolations in cases like "${var.project_id}", just use var.project_id. Also, the data you're using provides the member attribute, which already provides you the serviceAccount:... interpolation, without the need to create it manually.
